# How to fix unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have been trying to add the amount to the investment balance, but I don't know why it isn't working. This is where the problem is `investment.balance += investment.amount`

```
MY VIEW

def create_investment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        invest_form = InvestmentForm(request.POST)
        if invest_form.is_valid():
            investment = invest_form.save(commit=False)
            investment.balance += investment.amount
            investment.balance.save()
            investment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is successfull')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is not successfull! Try again.')
    else:
        invest_form = InvestmentForm()
    context = {'invest_form': invest_form}
    return render(request, 'create-investment.html', context)

MY MODEL
 
class Investment(models.Model):
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that "investment.balance.save()" is extra code
Remove it and test again
Also you can do it in a second way

```py
name = form.cleaned_data['name']
number = form.cleaned_date['phone_number']
p = Person(name=name, phone_number=number, date_subscr
```